# How to create sql query to insert values from another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which related to another table by 1:1.
The first table called 'Deal' which has: id, deal_ext_id fields 
The second table called 'Deal_Ext' which has: id, externalId, systemId fields.

I also have temp table which contains externalId, systemId fields which need to be inserted to the second table (Deal_Ext).

Because the relation between both tables (Deal, Deal_Ext) is 1:1, the foreign need also be updated when values are inserted to 'Deal_Ext' table.

How can I have a for loop, which getting through my temp table and first insert new line to 'Deal_Ext' with new Id, second, by this new Id, I will update 'Deal' table accordingly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phase 1: 
insert into deal_ext(external_id)
select  t.campaign_id
from tempdeal t;

Phase 2: 
update deal set deal_ext_id = (select e.id from tempdeal t, deal_ext e where t.campaign_id = e.external_id and t.deal_id = deal.id)

Solved!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this query:

```
insert into tableone(col1,col2) select col1,col2 from table2
```

Comment: I need to take care of 1:1 relation between both tables, so it's not solving the problem.